# Gradle: Setting up Scala project with Apache Spark in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, gradle

I am not able to setup a Scala project with Apache Spark dependency in Eclipse. Using a Scala IDE plugin and Gradle plugins in Eclipse. `build.gradle` project looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies{
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.2"
    compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.3'
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}

task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main = 'Main'
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.runtime
}
```

Under the `Referenced Libraries` I can see spark-core-2.3.jar. But I can't import any Spark library into Scala class.
I did try running `gradle eclipse` command but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referencing the wrong dependency - instead of `com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.3` (which belongs to another project, [Spark web framework](http://sparkjava.com/)), you should include:

```
compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.0.1'
```

This uses latest stable version (2.0.1).